# Why is my guessing game not giving errors but not working properly?

Tags: java

I copied a guessing game from a book where youre supposed to guess what number the program has generated and it will tell you if youre too low or too high, but my program keeps telling me I am too low, even if I enter a negative number or a number like 50.

````
public class Hilo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String playAgain = "";
        do {
            // Create a random number for the user to guess
            int theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);    
            // System.out.println( theNumber );
            int guess = 0;
            while (guess != theNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
                    guess = scan.nextInt();
                    if (guess < theNumber)
                        System.out.println(guess + " is too low. Try again.");
                    else if (guess > theNumber)
                        System.out.println(guess + " is too high. Try again.");
                    else
                        System.out.println(guess + " is correct. You win!");
                }   // End of while loop for guessing
                System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n)?");
                playAgain = scan.next();
            } while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Goodbye.");
            scan.close();
        }
    }```


edit:
````

1
1 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
2
2 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
3
3 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
4
4 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
5
5 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
6
6 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
9
9 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
8
8 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
7
7 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
10
10 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
11
11 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
12
12 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
13
13 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
14
14 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
15
15 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
16
16 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
17
17 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
18
18 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
19
19 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
20
20 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
21
21 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
22
22 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
23
23 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
24
24 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
25
25 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
26
26 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
27
27 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
28
28 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
29
29 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
30
30 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
31
31 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
32
32 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
33
33 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
34
34 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
35
35 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
36
36 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
37
37 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
38
38 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
39
39 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:

40
40 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
41
41 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
42
42 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
43
43 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
44
44 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
45
45 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
46
46 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:

47
47 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
48
48 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
49
49 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
50
50 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
51
51 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
52
52 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
53
53 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
54
54 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
55
55 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
56
56 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
57
57 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
58
58 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
59
59 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
60
60 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
61
61 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
62
62 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
65
65 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
63
63 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
64
64 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
65
65 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
66
66 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
67
67 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
68
68 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
6
6 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
69
69 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
80
80 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
7
0707 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:

70 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
70
70 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
71
71 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
72
72 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
73
73 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
74
74 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
75
75 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
76
76 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
77
77 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
78
78 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
79
79 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
80
80 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
81
81 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
82
82 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
83
83 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
84
84 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
85
85 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
86
86 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
87
87 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
88
88 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
89
89 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
90
90 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
91
91 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
92
92 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
93
93 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
94
94 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
95
95 is correct. You win!
Would you like to play again (y/n)?
y
Guess a number between 1 and 100:
4
4 is too low. Try again.
Guess a number between 1 and 100:

Comment: Wouldn't a negative number always be too low? -10 < 1

Comment: You say `Guess a number between 1 and 100:` and then you input a negative number.

Comment: i have tested both positive and negative numbers I have entered numbers like 50

Comment: You've commented out the line that outputs "theNumber" to the console, but when that's put back in, are you confirming that the number you are entering is actually less than the generated number?  What happens if you enter 200 - does it still say it's too low?

Comment: actually this is pretty weird i will post the response in console but scroll to number 95

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest is that you try a `System.out.println(theNumber);` inside your `do-while` loop but outside your `while` loop to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: it's actually fine i thought it didnt work but it did

Comment: @Jayden000001 ah ok I see. Well, think of trying to troubleshoot next time so that you know where and why the error is occurring!